# Link Firebase Analytics with DoubleClick (DFP)

Tags: firebase, google-dfp, firebase-analytics

We want to link firebase analytics with doubleclick for publishers. We had AdMob before and could use the ARPU (Average Revenue per User) statistics.

We could use the `ecommerce_purchase` and `in_app_purchase` feature inside the app for "putting" data to firebase analytics in order to see the ARPU. But we don't know the exact revenue a DFP ad brings within the code of the app.

Has someone tried to link them together or figured out how to retrieve the necessary values from DFP and how to use them in the code in order to set them properly for firebase analytics?

Comment: A Firebase Analytics integration with DFP has a lot of potential value and this is something we are carefully considering right now.